# Using PreferenceScreen/PreferenceActivity to configure home screen widgets

Tags: android

I'm creating an appwidget, where the user should be able to configure it before it is added to the home screen. To me, PreferenceScreen/PreferenceActivity seems perfect for the task, but the intention behind these classes seem to be configuring an actual application. I've searched, but cannot find any documentation or tutorials which covers this question.

Is it possible to configure a widget using these classes, or is the only alternative to configure it through an ordinary view?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You certainly can use a `PreferenceActivity` for this purpose. If you set it up as the `android:configure` activity in your widget configuration, though, you will have to do a bit of fancy footwork to then get your widget updated.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That's what I call a prompt and concise answer. As I'm new here I can't vote up your answer, but I will try to do it when my reputation goes up.

Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Mark any chance you could update the link, it seems to point to have gone from your repo

Comment: @Rob: Actually, right now, I don't have any app widgets with configuration screens, sorry. That project was deleted after Twitter changed its authentication model, breaking the code. I will edit the question to remove the link, though.

Comment: it's ok i found it via your repos history, hope you don't mind. https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/b01438e7f0fed8f795ddec4be43066905f03d0cc/AppWidget/TwitterWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/TWPrefs.java

Answer (score 1):

commonsWare:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/res/xml/widget_provider.xml
your example does not use a config-activity at all and thus certainly no PreferencesActivity.

As far as PreferencesActivities go,
it does NOT work to setResult(RESULT_CANCELED); in onCreate(9 and then setResult(...) in onBackPressed.
There are wired NullPointerExceptions deep in Launcher.java (line 88X).
However it does work do Provider.updateAppWidget() and setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue); in onCreate
and then handle further updates in onBackPressed.

The following snipped may help too:

```
onCreate() {
CheckBoxPreference dark = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("xyz");
dark.setChecked(false);
...
onBackPressed() {
CheckBoxPreference dark = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("xyz");
boolean checked = dark.isChecked();
```

...

Comment: I only saw your note today; please use comments to contact people regarding answers. The link was to a different project that has been deleted; I have now deleted the link from the answer. My apologies for any confusion.